# Why is my mypy.ini file not followed for no implicit optional checks during type checks?

Tags: python, types, fastapi, mypy, python-3.11

I have a `mypy.ini` file and I can confirm that it's getting picked up when I run `mypy --strict .` However, for some reason (even though I have the strictest settings enabled in my `mypy.ini` file) when it runs it's less strict than the default.

I have `no_implicit_optional = True` set and when I manually replaced `Optional[UUID]` with `UUID` below I should get `None` errors. However, I only get them if I run with mypy defaults.

```
class EvaluationResponse(BaseModel):
    id: UUID
    content_id: UUID
    context_id: UUID
    is_compliant: bool
    result: str
    confidence: int
```

Mypy.ini file:

```
[mypy]
# --- Paths ---
python_version = 3.11 

# Ignore venv files
exclude = ^venv/

# Specify the path to your source code (if it's not in the root folder)
# mypy_path = src

# --- Checking Options ---

# Type check the body of functions without type annotations
check_untyped_defs = True

# Disallow usage of generic types without explicit type parameters
disallow_any_generics = True

# Disallow subclassing of 'Any' type
disallow_subclassing_any = True

# For FastAPI to ensure that optional query parameters are also type-checked correctly
strict_optional = True

# Disallow calling functions without type annotations from a typed context
disallow_untyped_calls = True

# Disallow usage of decorators that don't have type annotations
disallow_untyped_decorators = True

# Disallow defining functions without type annotations or with incomplete type annotations
disallow_untyped_defs = True

# Flag for missing imports; set to True if you want to be strict,
ignore_missing_imports = False

# We can ignore for specific libraries if needed
disallow_any_unimported = True

# Disallow implicit Optional types when initializing variables as None or functions with default None arguments
no_implicit_optional = True

# Prevent implicitly re-exporting names imported from other modules
no_implicit_reexport = True

# Prohibit equality comparisons between non-overlapping types
strict_equality = True

# Warn about redundant uses of `cast()`
warn_redundant_casts = True

# Warn when returning a value with type `Any` from a function
warn_return_any = True

# Warn about unused config options in the mypy.ini file
warn_unused_configs = True

# Warn about `# type: ignore` comments that don't suppress any errors
warn_unused_ignores = True

# Turned this on so I don't have to package my top level folders
namespace_packages = False
explicit_package_bases = False

# --- Library specific settings ---

# Install 'mypy' plugins
plugins = pydantic.mypy, sqlalchemy.ext.mypy.plugin
```

I've tried running `mypy --strict --verbose .` and that tells me that it's picking up the `mypy.ini` file. This also confirmed to me that it found and ran on the file that I introduced the bug to.

I've tried to manually add flags `mypy --strict --no-implicit-optional .` to get the error but I still don't get it.

I tried moving the file around in my codebase to see if that made a difference.